How to display an image for electronic seal in pdf document with enveloppe API
I've add an electronic seal to the signature in the API call (createEnveloppe).
The seal is visible in the signature panel with Acrobat, but I want an image being visible in the PDF document (like the signer 'signHereTabs').
In the electronic Seal settings there is an image of the company, I need that image would be put into the document.
Here is the JSon for the seal in the createEnveloppe call :
"seals" : [ {
      "recipientId" : "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "recipientSignatureProviders" : [ {
        "sealName" : "XXXXXXXXXXX"
      } ],
      "routingOrder" : "2"
    } ],

May I add some tab (companyTab, other) ?
What should I do ?
I've looked the API documentation, but I didn't find...

You are missing the tabs element inside the seal.
See here part of a JSON: (this is taken from https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/how-to-certify-your-documents-using-docusign-electronic-seal-api)
"recipients": {
   "seals": [
     {
       "recipientId": "1",
       "routingOrder": "1",
       "recipientSignatureProviders": [
         {
           "sealDocumentsWithTabsOnly": "false",
           "sealName": "b9a15451-3ef4-4a5d-8d60-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
         }
       ],
       "tabs": {
         "signHereTabs": [
           {
             "anchorString": "myESealAnchor",
             "recipientId": "1"
           }
         ]
       }
     }
   ],


Thanks, that's exactly what I need !!
